# Text is not updated when I changed my Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a small problem, it is my first time using redux, I am trying to just edit my title, so Here is two components I have : ( I explained below what I expected to see and did not get it )

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { changeTitle } from "./redux/actions/changeTitle"
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.myTitle}</h1>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.changeTitle("That")}>Change</button>
            </div>);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        myTitle: state.title
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        changeTitle: changeTitle
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test);
```

Here is How I get the title for first time :

```
export default function titleReducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type !== "TITLE_CHANGED") {
        console.log(state);
        console.log(action);

        return "qlq"
    } else {
        return state
    }
}
```

Here is my changeTitle reducer :

```
export default function titleChangeReducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === "TITLE_CHANGED") {
        console.log(state);
        console.log(action);

        return {
            title: "test again", ...state
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

So I expected then when I change the state, I will get changes on my view directly, but to be honnest I dont know even if I changed my state, When I click my Button that what console.log give me :

> {title: "test again"}
>   {type: "TITLE_CHANGED", payload: "That"}

This is my change title action :

```
export function changeTitle(toThat) {
    return {
        type: "TITLE_CHANGED",
        payload: toThat
    }
}
```

And Here is how I combined my reducers :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import titleReducer from "./titleReducer";
import titleChangeReducer from "./titleToChange";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    title: titleReducer,
    titleChanging: titleChangeReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

If there anything else to add to make the question more clear, please ask me to add it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the reason for having two title related reducers?

Comment: No reason, I thought it won't cause a problem, you think it is the problem ? Because I noticed that my redux state is not changing in the compoenent.

Comment: Well I guess it depends on how you expect the second reducer to work. There's nothing wrong with having it, I'm just making sure you aren't trying to use it to make updates to the first reducer.

Comment: Well Yes, Lol, I am using it to make changes on the first one

Comment: Ah then thats a problem. They are two independent parts of your overall state. Both can listen to the same actions, but they cannot modify each others part of state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your case, I think you should remove the `titleChangeReducer`.

Then just modify your existing reducer to handle state updates. Something like this:

```js
export default function titleReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type !== "TITLE_CHANGED") {
    return action.payload; // This will update your reducer state.
  } else {
    return state
  }
}
```

I can't say for sure if you should keep the second reducer or not, but if you need it here are some things to consider.

1. You should initialize your state either with a const or in the declaration:
   `export default function titleReducer(state = [], action) {`. Then just return `state` instead of the empty array at the end. Otherwise your state will be overwritten every action dispatch.
2. You are changing data types. Your state defaults to an array, but you are returning an object for type "TITLE_CHANGED". Keep them consistent.